# Python: apply slice values within a callable function

Tags: python

I am dealing with a very long list, which represents flattened tuples. E.g.:

```
vll = ['1', '.32', '2', '3.234', '3', '.23', '4', '8.987', ... for a long time]
```

I want to be able to recompose the tuple, and slice it to the appropriate length. Ideally, I would like to slice the list before recomposing it into a tuple. How do I determine the slice values put on a custom method.

```
def tuple_list(vll, tuple_length=2):
    start, stop, step = sliced  # those slice values I don't know how to find
    l = vll[start:stop * tuple_length]  
    tuple_list = zip([int(i) for i in l[0::2]], [float(v) for v in l[1::2]])
    return tuple_list[::step]
```

So when I use this function, I would like it to look something like a traditional python list:

```
>>> tuple_list(vll)[:2]
>>> [(1, .32), (2, 3.234)]
```

I know I can make arguments for the slice values in the function call. I also could do this:

```
>>> l = vll[:4]
>>> tuple_list = zip([int(i) for i in l[0::2]], [float(v) for v in l[1::2]])
>>> tuple_list
>>> [(1, .32), (2, 3.234)]
```

or

```
>>> tuple_list = zip([int(i) for i in vll[0::2]], [float(v) for v in vll[1::2]])
>>> tuple_list[:2]
>>> [(1, .32), (2, 3.234)]
```

UPDATE: The below code answers my question. What I did is define a class, rather than a function, and I can put all of the function logic inside the class's `__getitem__` method. Any thoughts or input on the approach would be great.

```
class tuple_list(object):
    def __init__(self, flat_list, tuple_length=2):
        self.flat_list = flat_list
        self.tuple_length = tuple_length

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        base_list = self.flat_list[item.start: item.stop * self.tuple_length]

        tuple_list = zip(
            [int(i) for i in base_list[0::2]],
            [float(v) for v in base_list[1::2]]
        )

        return tuple_list[::item.step]

>>> tuple_list(range(1000000))[3:48:9]
>>> [(3, 4.0), (21, 22.0), (39, 40.0), (57, 58.0), (75, 76.0), (93, 94.0)]
```

Comment: You can't get the slice values inside the method, since you're slicing the *result* of the method call -- i.e., the slice doesn't happen until after your method is called.  Why don't you just make your method accept `start`, `stop`, and `step` as regular arguments?

Comment: @BrenBarn I can make start, stop, step as regular arguments, but I wanted to retain the slice function which is a part of a normal list, if for know other reason that the legibility and obviousness.

Comment: Also, common Django lingo is `Model.objects.filter(id__lt=100)[:5]`, and this does not pull all the rows from the model and then slice, it only pulls 5 rows. That's why I think the might be doable.

Comment: It is possible, but what you have to do is have `tuple_list` return a "magic" object that handles slicing.  For a simple task like this it's probably easier just to pass the slice start/stop/step as arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
all_points = range(100)
slice_size = 3
sliced_points = zip(* [iter(all_points)]*slice_size)
```

Is my favorite way to do this ... **assuming I understand the question properly** ...

however it truncates the list if it has an odd number of points left over (eg only 2 points left with a slice required of 3)

if you want this end bit you can easily enough do

```
sliced_points.append(all_points[-(len(all_points)%slice_size):])
```

if you want to only look at a range just pass in `my_list = all_points[start:stop]` instead of all points where you are doing your grouping

Comment: Awesome. I was also helping I would find this type of snippet as part of asking my question. The other part of my question was the bit about using slicing notion, so if `all_points = range(1000000000)`, then `tuple_points = all_points[:300]` which gives `len(sliced_points) = 100`. What I am hoping to do is wrap this inside a function that would most legibility accomplish `zip(*[iter(range(1000000000)]*slice_size)[:100]` without having to zip / iterate over the whole `range(1000000000)`.

Comment: just use `iter(whole_range[start:stop])` instead of `whole_range_of_values`